# DYNAMO DB* Query to Insert and update only an specific array element in a document

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Need mongodb query : if I get a `order` , `vendorID` in input params that already exists with specific `orderNumber` I need to update it in `orders` array by replacing the whole existing order element with that `orderNumber` with newly provided order in input params,  else insert it

Suppose input param has three attributes :

1. `orderNumber : "order2"`
2. `order: {"orderNumber":"order2", "data":"NEW_DATA_FROM_INPUT" }`
3. `vendorId : "vendor1"`

Here is the sample data in DB:

```json
{
  "_id":1,
  "vendorId":"Vendor1",
  "orders":[
    {
      "orderNumber":"order1",
      "data":"data1"
    },
    {
      "orderNumber":"order2",
      "data":"data2"
    }
  ]
}
```

THE QUERY SHOULD UPDATE THE RECORD AS BELOW:

```json
{
  "_id":1,
  "vendorId":"Vendor1",
  "orders":[
    {
      "orderNumber":"order1",
      "data":"data1"
    },
    {
      "orderNumber":"order2",
      "data":"NEW_DATA_FROM_INPUT"  // !!
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried `$set`, `$addtoSet` but they cannot be used together on same path due to mongo limitations.

Comment: why not just split into conditional, check first if the order exists, and then based on that, either add the element or update it?

Comment: Good question, but would like to minimize the calls to DB so there will not be any data loss meanwhile.

Comment: _"... else insert it"_  What if `"vendorId"` in the input params doesn't match any document?

Comment: there is a diff logic to handle if vendorId dosent match and the query will not be executed

Comment: Are you also guaranteed that `"orders"` will exist and be an array?

Comment: not guaranteed. But if it exists, it is guaranteed to be an array.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use an [aggregation pipeline in the update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

N.B.:  Comments in `update` listing below.  Depending on the app/driver you are using, you may need to change `db.collection.update` to something else (and you probably don't want/need `{"multi": true}`).

```js
db.collection.update({
  // find doc with correct "vendorId"
  "vendorId": "Vendor1"
},
// use pipeline
[{
  // rebuild "orders"
  "$set": {
    "orders": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          // from input params
          "orderParam": {
            "orderNumber": "order2",
            "data": "NEW_DATA_FROM_INPUT"
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$cond": [
            // does "orders.orderNumber" exist and is array?
            {
              "$eq": [{"$type": "$orders.orderNumber"}, "array"]
            },
            // yes, "orders.orderNumber" exists and is array
            {
              "$cond": [
                // does an order need rewriten "data"?
                {
                  "$in": ["order2", "$orders.orderNumber"]
                },
                // yes, rewrite specific order, keep the rest
                {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$orders",
                    "as": "order",
                    "in": {
                      "$cond": [
                        // is this the order?
                        {
                          "$eq": ["$$order.orderNumber", "$$orderParam.orderNumber"]
                        },
                        // yes, rewrite this order
                        {
                          "$mergeObjects": [
                            "$$order",
                            {"data": "$$orderParam.data"}
                          ]
                        },
                        // not the order, so keep it
                        "$$order"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                // no, order is not there, so just append it
                {
                  "$concatArrays": ["$orders", ["$$orderParam"]]
                }
              ]
            },
            // nobody home, create it
            ["$$orderParam"]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VrXXNawpakK) where you will see various test cases.

Answer (score 0):

In case of updation, we can use positional operation "***$***" with *updateOne() or updateMany()* which helps in updating the first occurrence to be updated with the provided values.

For eg. In the above case we need to update the 2nd index object value.

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id:1,"orders.orderNumber":"order2"},{$set:{ "orders.$.data": "NEW_DATA_FROM_INPUT" }});
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, your query would only work for update, but I would like to insert {"orderNumber":"order2", "data":"NEW_DATA_FROM_INPUT" } incase if it does not exist.

Comment: Hi @av149, in that case you can use 

```db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id: 1, "orders.orderNumber": "order2" },
    { $set: { "orders.$.data": "NEW_DATA_FROM_INPUT" } },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

Hope, this helps :)